# Comparing all the objects in json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have about 25 objects of the similar kind and I need to check if 2 objects have the same `ParentId` and store those 2 file notes in separate data variable. How do I write the logic so as each object's `ParentId` is compared to every other object's `ParentId`?

```js
[
  { id: 1, Name: "abc", Date: "xyz", ParentId: 11, },
  { id: 2, Name: "fhj", Date: "sgj", ParentId: 11, },
  { id: 3, Name: "fhk", Date: "xyz", ParentId: 10, },
  //...
]
```

So far I have this method in which I am storing only the `ParentId` that is
not `null` in `newData` and then in `RelatedFNData` I have only the `ParentId` stored then I wrote a for each loop and I am storing the value I get from that loop in `currentdata` to treat it as a constant so that I could compare. I am stuck at the next step

```js
function displayRelatedFN(dataToFilter) {
  let newData = dataToFilter.filter(x => x.ParentId !== null);
  let RelatedFNData = newData.map(x => x.ParentId);

  for (var id in RelatedFNData) {
    let currentId = RelatedFNData[id];

    for (var id1 in RelatedFNData) {
      if (RelatedFNData[id1] == currentId) {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that the "json" is invalid. Do you mean "JavaScript array of objects" instead?

Comment: Please demonstrate what you have tried to solve your issue. Then we can help you identify the cause of any issues you have. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas I tried adding a for each loop but I am unable to form the custom compare condition as I recently started working on javascript

Comment: @Andreas I have added the function I tried to write and explained my approach

Comment: I fixed some problems in your question. Please spent some time on your next question on the format (the text, and the code) -> [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects. `RelatedFNData` is an array (of numbers)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const foo = [{
  id:1,
  Name: "abc",
  Date: "xyz",
  ParentId:11,
 },
 {
 id:2,
  Name: "fhj",
  Date: "sgj",
  ParentId:11,

 },
 {
  id:3,
  Name: "fhk",
  Date: "xyz",
  ParentId:10,
 }];
let rep = []; 

for(let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++){
  for(let j = i + 1; j < foo.length; j++){
    if(foo[i].ParentId === foo[j].ParentId){
      rep = [...rep, foo[i], foo[j]];
    }
  }
}
console.log(rep);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this (from this [example](https://codehandbook.org/javascript-find-duplicate-objects-array/))

```
let objList = [{
  "parentId": 5,
  "name": "June"
}, {
  "parentId": 4,
  "name": "Jane"
}, {
  "parentId": 3,
  "name": "Julia"
}, {
  "parentId": 2,
  "name": "Nancy"
}, {
  "parentId": 5,
  "name": "June"
}, {
  "parentId": 5,
  "name": "June"
}];

let uniqueList = [];
let dupList = [];

function contains(list, item) {
  let filtered_item = list.filter((i) => {
    return i.parentId === item.parentId
  });
  return !!filtered_item.length;
}

function pushToUniqueList(item) {
  if (!contains(uniqueList, item)) uniqueList.push(item);
}

function pushToDuplicateList(item) {
  if (!contains(dupList, item)) dupList.push(item);
}

for (let i = 0; i < objList.length; i++) {
  if (contains(uniqueList, objList[i])) {
    pushToDuplicateList(objList[i]);
  } else {
    pushToUniqueList(objList[i]);
  }
}

console.log('Duplicate list is ', dupList);
console.log('Unique list is ', uniqueList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//let data = yourdata

result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.ParentId] = r[a.ParentId] || [];
    r[a.ParentId].push(a);
    return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

get your answer in result object

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to store the array of children for the spesific parentId:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, Name: "abc", Date: "xyz", ParentId: 11, },
  { id: 2, Name: "fhj", Date: "sgj", ParentId: 11, },
  { id: 3, Name: "fhk", Date: "xyz", ParentId: 10, },
]
const obj= {}
data.forEach(dataRow => {
   obj[dataRow.ParentId] ? obj[dataRow.ParentId].push(dataRow) : obj[dataRow.ParentId] = [dataRow]
})
console.log(obj)
```

Then, since you have the array of data for each `parentId` you can render them seperately by:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  const data = obj[key]
  return(
    <div key={data.id}> {data.Name} </div>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a code snippet with a little explanation. Hope it helps understand it better

```js
    let arr = [{
      "id":1,
      "Name": "abc",
      "Date": "xyz",
      "ParentId":11,
     },
     {
      "id":2,
      "Name": "fhj",
      "Date": "sgj",
      "ParentId":11,

     },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "Name": "fhk",
      "Date": "xyz",
      "ParentId":10,
     }]
     
     
      
let final = arr.reduce((acc, b) => {
    //We are trying to group by ParentId
  //So a new object will be created with keys the ParentId's
  // { 10: [.....], 11: [.....], 12: [.....]}
  //If a key is not found in new object, then just create a new array
  if (!acc[b.ParentId]) {
    acc[b.ParentId] = []
  }
  
  //Add this object to this key's array
  acc[b.ParentId].push(b);

  //return the updated object
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(final)
```